# Why does this multithreading script hang?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

The code seems to always hang at this line in the stack `wait_for_tstate_lock elif lock.acquire(block, timeout)`. Am I using `Lock()` or `Semaphore()` wrong?

```
import concurrent.futures import csv import threading

import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

from discovery.featurizer import UrlFeaturizer

semaphore = threading.Semaphore(50)


def run_featurizer():
    res = UrlFeaturizer(url).run(dataset)[1]
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keys = UrlFeaturizer("1.1.1.1").run("")[0]
    with open("num_features.csv", "a") as f:
        csv_out = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
        csv_out.writeheader()
        with semaphore:
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
                futures = []
                datasets = [
                    "benign_domains.csv",
                    "dmca_domains.csv",
                ]
                for dataset in datasets:
                    urls = pd.read_csv(dataset, header=None).iloc[:, 0].to_list()
                    with tqdm(total=len(urls)) as pbar:
                        for url in urls:
                            futures.append(executor.submit(run_featurizer, ))
                        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                            pbar.update()
                            with threading.Lock() as lock:
                                csv_out.writerow(future.result())
                                f.flush()
```

Minimal reproducible example of UrlNumFeaturizer:

```
class UrlFeaturizer(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        try:
            self.response = requests.get(
                prepend_protocols(self.url), headers=headers, timeout=5
            )
        except Exception:
            self.response = None
        try:
            self.whois = whois.query(self.url).__dict__
        except Exception:
            self.whois = None
        try:
            self.soup_c = BeautifulSoup(
                self.response.content,
                features="lxml",
                from_encoding=self.response.encoding,
            )
        except Exception:
            self.soup_c = None

    def lookup_whois(self) -> int:
        return int(False) if self.whois else int(True)

    def lookup_domain_age(self) -> int:
        if self.whois and self.whois["creation_date"]:
            return (date.today() - self.whois["creation_date"].date()).days
        return

    def verify_ssl(self) -> bool:
        try:
            ssl_cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((self.url, 443), timeout=10)
            return int(True) if ssl_cert else int(False)
        except Exception:
            return

    def check_security(self) -> bool:
        try:
            requests.head(f"https://{self.url}", timeout=10)
            return int(True)
        except Exception:
            return int(False)

    def has_com_tld(self):
        return int(True) if extract_tld(self.url) == "com" else int(False)

    def run(self, dataset=None):
        data = {
            "url": self.url,
            "uses_whois_privacy": self.lookup_whois(),
            "domain_age": self.lookup_domain_age(),
            "has_ssl": self.verify_ssl(),
            "is_secure": self.check_security(),
            "has_com_tld": self.has_com_tld(),
            "label": Path(dataset).stem,
        }
        return data.keys(), data
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger and inspect the different threads, in particular what they're waiting for at that moment.

Comment: @larsks I realized that just after pressing Enter. :-/ Since basically everything is done with the semaphore held, what's the use of the semaphore? And since a new `Lock` is created for every `future`, that doesn't seem very useful either.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code (missing imports, undefined variable references, etc). Can you update it to provide an [mcve] that we can run to reproduce the issue you're asking about?

Comment: @larsks I tried running it without the semaphore, unfortunately I got the same result (ˊ̥̥̥̥̥ ³ ˋ̥̥̥̥̥)

Comment: @larsks I added a minimal reproducible example of the UrlNumFeaturizer import, which is what I think you were referring to. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ariyasas94 Can you describe what you are trying to use the `Semaphore` for? Because as currently coded it does not seem particularly useful.

Comment: @RolandSmith Honestly I'm pretty new to this so this might sound stupid but I thought you had to throttle ThreadPoolExecutor so it'd didn't open up too many connections. Thing is, I removed it at your guys' suggestion but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @ariyasas94 If you reduce the size of your Pool as I suggest in my answer, this will automatically throttle the amount of network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `Lock` under the line

```
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)
```

because you're iterating over the futures anyway. So all writing to the CSV output file is done sequentially.

You are also creating a new `Lock` for every `future`, so the lock doesn't do much anyway.

If you want to limit the amount of threads running at the same time, remove the semaphore and reduce the size of your Pool.

Comment: Ok, good to know. This actually helped somewhat. The script wouldn't run at all, but the problem is now it gets hung on the 4th iteration.